# probability of a particular outcome with two dice

Tags: probability

Throwing two dice what are my chances of getting ten?

I would say that probability $\frac{1}{6}$ because I can get ten with

$6 + 4$

or

$5 + 5.$

Is my idea correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Since any die can give a number between $1$ and $6$, you have $36$ possible outcomes (do you see why? I think this is another reason for your mistake).

Three couples $(a,b)$ of values sum up to $10$ (you forgot to mention $4+6$).

So your probability is $\dfrac1{12}$.